# Online DNS with automatic resolution of local IPs

Tags: http, web, dns, web-development-server

I remember using an online service that automaticaly translate "fake" subdomain to local IPs.

For example 192.168.1.1.THATSERVICE.COM would resolve to 192.168.1.1

But i can't manage to find that service anymore ...

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You may find your answer on [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/591732/dns-domain-which-resolves-names-to-local-ip-addresses), there are several different approaches eventually.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I found on this page the solution i was thinking of, it was http://xip.io/

Comment: My pleasure, I'll post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the functionality that you seek on the following [link](https://superuser.com/questions/591732/dns-domain-which-resolves-names-to-local-ip-addresses)

There are several services listed, which might be useful for the job

Answer (score 0):

For further reference, the specific service i was describing is http://xip.io/